# zoom in and out from a picturebox

Tags: c#, zooming, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

I'm having a form with a pictureBox, showing an image. I have also 2 buttons - Zoom In and Zoom out. When the image is zoomed in I want to able to drag it asides to be able to see other parts in the image.
The problem is that when I click the zoom in button it works fine, but the dragging doesn't move the image inside the pictureBox (I can drag the image, but it always returns to same position when I release the mouse button), and when I zoom out the image is not centered and shows only a part of the image that has been zoomed into, and it also changes the size of the picture box and changes its location on the form.

my code:

```
    private double ZOOM_INTERVAL = 0.25;
    private double currentZoom = 1.0;

    //zoom out from product image
    private void ZoomOutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentZoom > 0.5)
        {
            currentZoom -= ZOOM_INTERVAL;
            ResizeImage();
        }
    }

    //zoom in to product image
    private void ZoomInBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentZoom += ZOOM_INTERVAL;
        ResizeImage();
    }

    private void ResizeImage()
    {
        Bitmap img = initialImage;
        if (img != null)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img, Convert.ToInt32(initialImage.Width * currentZoom), Convert.ToInt32(initialImage.Height * currentZoom));
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            mouseDownLoc = e.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
              Point currentMousePos = e.Location;
              int distanceX = currentMousePos.X - mouseDownLoc.X;
              int distanceY = currentMousePos.Y - mouseDownLoc.Y;
              int newX = pictureBox1.Location.X + distanceX;
              int newY = pictureBox1.Location.Y + distanceY;
              if(newX + pictureBox1.Image.Width < pictureBox1.Image.Width && pictureBox1.Image.Width + newX > panel1.Width)

                    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(newX, pictureBox1.Location.Y);

              if(newY + pictureBox1.Image.Height < pictureBox1.Image.Height && pictureBox1.Image.Height + newY > panel1.Height)

                    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, newY);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to zoom-in and zoom-out a image in picturebox using mouse wheels in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734934/how-to-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-a-image-in-picturebox-using-mouse-wheels-in-c)

Comment: the answer at this question changes the size of the pictureBox, which is something I don't want.

Comment: Use the `PictureBox.Top` and `PictureBox.Left` properties instead of `Location`.