# How to zoom with scroll wheel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scroll, zooming, mousewheel

I have a windows forms project in which I want to implement scrolling. I attempted to use the second answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734934/how-to-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-a-image-in-picturebox-using-mouse-wheels-in-c)

so now my code looks like this:

```
  void pictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {

      if (e.Delta != 0)
      {
          if (e.Delta <= 0)
          {
              //set minimum size to zoom
              if (pictureBox1.Width < 50)
                  return;
          }
          else
          {
              //set maximum size to zoom
              if (pictureBox1.Width > 500)
                  return;
          }
          pictureBox1.Width += Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Width * e.Delta / 1000);
          pictureBox1.Height += Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Height * e.Delta / 1000);
      }
```

but it only behaves like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9T_vgkoSWs&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the [SizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your PictureBox. By default, this is the enum `Normal`. Given your demonstration, I suggest you use the `Zoom` enum value for the image to grow and shrink with your mouse wheel as the picture box is resized.